# MS Access connection to SQL Server (2016) suddenly fails

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, connection, odbc

I am quite lost, so I turn to you in search for help.

I am working on an MS Access 2016 database frontend. This FE utilizes a `MS SQL Server (2016)` backend, using ODBC to connect to the tables.

The situation is the following:

I open a form "`myform_A`" which shows data from a table.

I click a button which starts some process in the background. This process also needs some data from a (2nd) table: `tblMitarbeiter` . This table if NOT the source of the form.

All of a sudden - but unfortunately in 95% of all cases Access tells me error 3146 occured (ODBC timeout).

All tables, also the one I need some data from in the process (the 2nd table) is accessible using the Access navigation bar. ODBC to these tables works.
... but the connection using VBA does NOT work (but throws error 3146).

The problem occurs at different machines, over LAN and over VPN and fails at the line:

```
Set rstMitarbeiter = dbsMitarbeiter.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

**ID_Mitarbeiter** is available at runtime.

ODBC Connection string:

```
ODBC;DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.100.19;DATABASE=MYDBNAME;Max Pool Size=100;UID=myusername;PWD=secretPW
```

Please note:

- I am trying to get only 1 record!
- code **WORKS** when I put it in a public sub and start it, using the direct window in VBA, without having the form "myform_A" open, but directly after opening the Access file.
- No difference if I remove MAX POOL SIZE from the connection string (I actually added that to avoid this error - with no result)

I have

- tried pass through query - no luck, same bad result
- checked for Auto-Close on SQL Server for this database. It is turned OFF.
- tried SQL Native client to connect to the server - no difference
- set the Querytimeout - no difference
- max pool size on SQL-server is set to 32767

So - what can I do?

Where could the bug be hiding?

Any ideas / suggestions?

Thank you so much already.

The code I am running on the 2nd table (in te process after pressing the button) is

```
Dim dbsMitarbeiter As DAO.Database
Dim rstMitarbeiter As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblMitarbeiter WHERE ID_Mitarbeiter=" & ID_Antragsteller & ";"

Set dbsMitarbeiter = CurrentDb()

dbsMitarbeiter.QueryTimeout = 60
Set rstMitarbeiter = dbsMitarbeiter.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)      

Do While Not rstMitarbeiter.EOF
    somevar = Nz(rstMitarbeiter.Fields("myfield"), 0)
    someothervar = Nz(rstMitarbeiter.Fields("someotherfield"), 0)
    rstMitarbeiter.MoveNext
Loop

rstMitarbeiter.Close
If Not rstMitarbeiter Is Nothing Then Set rstMitarbeiter = Nothing
dbsMitarbeiter.Close
If Not dbsMitarbeiter Is Nothing Then Set dbsMitarbeiter = Nothing
```

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read, about, and start using parameterized queries. The code you posted is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your input. I agree with you that prevention of sql injection is needed, but in this case I do not see a problem. I missed to show declaration of the variable ID_Antragsteller - which id long integer. Therefore I do not see a problem. If I am missing something, I would welcome you to point it out to me.

Comment: Not using parameters for queries however is a bad habit. Just use parameters and do it the right way. It takes hardly any extra effort. Not sure why top 1 as it looks like you are using the primary key as the predicate. And avoid using select *.

Comment: My guess is you have some locking going on. But really hard to say.

Comment: Yes, locking seems somewhere ... I am testing with dbOpenForwardOnly now. Worked 5x, but then failed as well :-(. I will probably remove the * later on once it works.

Comment: I was unable to solve the problem. I checked all queries for locking. 
I also tried sp_who and sp_lock on the sql server, but I do not have permissions for these commands :-(
I also moved the code that fails to another part in my general code, so that it is run later when two open forms have been closed already: Still no positive result. I am still unable to write a new record to a (changing(!)) table.

Comment: Well then ask your DBA to either run those or give you permission. You can't solve a locking problem if you can't run the procedures needed to do the analysis.

Comment: Yes @Sean Lange, I did that. Now we see. Thank you for your suggestions and help.